# Using matplotlib colormaps for probability ratios

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colormap

I'm trying to create a heatmap (through seaborn) showing the ratio of two probabilities, and I can't figure out how to make the colormap reasonable. My data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Since my value is the ratio of two probabilities, they lie on the interval `(0, infinity)`, with 1 meaning an equal probability. Therefore, I want a diverging colormap, with a center of 1, where `n^{x}` and `n^{-x}` are equidistant from the center of the colormap, but on opposite sides for all `n`, `x` (hopefully, that makes sense).

Originally, I tried playing around with `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm`, but this doesn't support diverging colormaps. `matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm` doesn't allow me to choose the center. I also believe they are not appropriate because my values are already normalized, so I think I want a linear color scale (though I'm unsure about this).

Then, I tried remapping my values so that every ratio less than 1 is mapped to its negative inverse: `ratios[ratios<1] = -1/ratios[ratios<1]`. This is a reasonable remapping: 2 is the equivalent of -2 (numerator twice as likely, and denominator twice as likely, respectively), etc. Then plotting them with `center=0` gets me a reasonable map, but 0 isn't my center. 1 and -1, respectively, are my centers. Is there a way to extend the center of a colormap so it includes multiple values (in my case, the interval `[-1, 1]`)? Or to mask it somehow?

I feel like that's my best way forward, but I'd be open to any suggestions (especially if someone knows how to get the colormap I want without remapping the values).

Here's a small working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), columns=['A','B'])
df['id1'] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
df['id2'] = [0, 1, 0, 1]
df['C'] = df.A / df.B
```

If we plot the above using a regular linear colormap, via the following call:

```
sns.heatmap(df.pivot('id1','id2','C'), center=1)
```

then we get [image: 1].

This isn't what we want because 2 is equidistant from 0 on the colorscale, whereas we want it to be equidistant from .5

If we do the mapping I did above: `df.C[df.C < 1] = -1/df.C[df.C<1]` and plot using `sns.heatmap(df.pivot('id1','id2','C'), center=0)`, we get [image: 2]

which is not ideal because those pale blue squares are basically -1 and should be much closer to grey.

Comment: I noticed I'm being downvoted. If users could leave comments to let me know why and how I can improve this question, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Now you are at zero again ;) But it would help if you could create a minimal working example. You already seem to have tried some things with a *reasonable map* as the result, if you can reproduce that with a minimal example and post it here, your question is perfectly fine and I'm sure that someone can help.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a brief example which hopefully clears things up.

Comment: Didn't see your previous edits, but this is definitely a +1